# Custom fields and global subscriptions for Meteor user accounts

Tags: mongodb, meteor, user-accounts

I'm adding custom data to Meteor user accounts for the first time. I've been able to add custom fields without difficulty and I know they're there because I can see them in Mongol. I am publishing via a global subscription so how do I then go about reading data from individual fields? It seems the syntax is very different from that when using publish/subscribe methods.

So, I have user accounts like this (as seen in Mongol):

```
"_id": "#################",
  "profile": {
    "name": "Test User"
  },
  "customfields": {
    "customfield1": [
      "A","B","C"
    ]
  }
}
```

In `server/main.js` I have the following

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields:{customfields:1}});
});
```

This seems to be publishing fine. But what code do I use to render the cursor as data? I've been using variations on code like this in `client/main.js` and having no success:

```
var stuff = Meteor.users.find(this.userId).fetch();
console.log(stuff.customfield1);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Typo: you are filtering on `{ fields: { customfield: 1 }}` instead of `{fields:{ customfields: 1 }}`

Comment: Sorry, yes, there's a typo in the example – but that's not there in my actual working code, so sadly that's not the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyCollection.find()` returns a *cursor* whereas `MyCollection.findOne()` returns an *object*, i.e. a single mongodb document.

A *publication* **must** return a *cursor* or *array of cursors*. You publication is fine.

You are basically trying to make the `customfields` key of the user object visible on the client. (The `profile` key is automatically published by Meteor).

On the client, where you are doing:

```
var stuff = Meteor.users.find(this.userId).fetch();
```

You can simply use:

```
var stuff = Meteor.user();
```

or

```
var stuff = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
```

Then `stuff.customfields` will contain what you're looking for.

The second form is way too verbose for me unless you're looking for a different user than the logged in user.

**Note**: `this.userId` on the client will *not* be the `userId` of the current user, it will be *undefined*. That only works on the server. That may actually be the root cause of your problem. In addition, your publications must be *ready()* for the data to be available. This isn't true immediately after login for example.

Comment: Ah, perfect. It seems I had written working code in earlier in the process but I wasn't aware of the _ready()_ issue. I will address this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since customfield1 is nested in customfields, did you try stuff.customfields.customfield1?

Comment: Yes, and in fact I can get the console to log an array (rather than undefined or an error) but it's an empty one.